# Conexão SQL server com aplicação android

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio

Como conectar uma aplicação android ao banco de dados do sql server ?

Comment: Faz um backend que retorna os dados do banco e chame as rotas do backend!

Comment: Já há algo a respeito aqui -> [dúvida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247465/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-sql-server-database)